# Is there any Mongodb Data backup utility

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meanjs

I am working on mean.JS application, need to provide data backup and restore functionality for user 
I've come across [mongodb-backup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-backup) but I've issue in using this, backup file is storing in a folder where code is executed i.e `__dirname` is there any alternative option for storing back-up file in any other location ?

```
var backup = require('mongodb-backup');
backup({
        uri: 'uri',
        root: __dirname,
        // write files into this dir
        callback: function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            } else {
                console.log('finish');
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens when you provide "root" as some other directive instead of __dirname ?

More than that why you want to back up and restore functionality from node code itself. There are plenty of tools from mongo to achieve this -

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-and-restore-tools/

cloud based - https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/backups/

If you want periodic backups and restore then you can create crons and scripts to achieve that.

Comment: if i execute file as sudo and when i give other directive instead of __dirname this works

`__dirname = '/home/srinivas/Documents'
    console.log("this is the file location"+__dirname);
    backup({
        uri: 'mongodb://localhost/wj-iothub-dev',
        root: __dirname,
        tar: 'Backup.tar',
        // write files into this dir
        callback: function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            } else {
                console.log('finish');
            }
        }
});`

Comment: It worked !!! But still it would be good if you do this with trusted mongo utilities.